# Optional string in Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to add an optional string to an URL. I've tried this:

```
map ":category/p:id(/:title)" => ...
```

The title parameter should be optional, so that the user can insert a optional title or leave it. Sadly this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it depends on what version of Ruby on Rails you are using.

### Rails 3

```
  
    match ':category/p:id(/:title)', :to => 'category#edit'
```

### Rails 2

```
  
    map.connect ':category/p:id/:title, :controller => 'category', :action => 'edit', :title => 'default title'
```